# Detect focus initiated by tab key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I want to detect the focus event of an element, but only if it was initiated by the user pressing the tab key. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />
<input type="text" id="detect" />
```

If the user is focused on `#foo` and presses <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I want the event to fire once `#detect` becomes focused (or a conditional inside the focus event to be true). Conversely, if the user simply clicks on the `#detect` field to focus it, I do not want the event to fire (or I want the conditional inside the focus event call to be false).

I don't want to use the keydown event of `#foo` and check if the tab key was pressed, as I want the approach to be independent of any other element.

I looked through the console output of the following code, but couldn't notice any real differences between the two methods of focusing:

```
$('#detect').on('focus', function(e){
   console.log(e); 
});
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPGLm/))

Is this possible to accomplish in a relatively simple way?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Update:** change the listener around:

```
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 9 && $('#detect:focus').length) {
        alert('I was tabbed!');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPGLm/7/

**Original:**
I know you have accepted an answer but you could test the button pressed using the following:

```
$('#detect').on('focus', function(e){
    $(window).keyup(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 9) {
           alert('I was tabbed!');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPGLm/1/

Comment: Hm, this actually seems like a better solution.. I unselected the answer, I'll hold off on selecting for now.

Comment: You might be on to something, but you're not there. *Every time* `#detect` gains focus, a global event listener will be registered, that looks for a tab *anywhere*. So if focus and blur `#detect` three times by clicking in and outside it, blur it, and then hit tab so that `#foo` gains focus, you'll still get three "I was tabbed" alerts.

Answer (score 12):

A more responsive solution would be to use two listeners:

```
var mousedown = false;
$('#detect').on('mousedown', function () {
    mousedown = true;
});

$('#detect').on('focusin', function () {
    if(!mousedown) {
        // logic
    }
    mousedown = false;
});
```

Fiddle showing the difference in speed:

http://jsfiddle.net/u2y45/1/

Comment: The reason this works is because `mousedown` gets triggered before `focusin` when clicking. `click` gets triggered after `focusin` so just those two cannot be used for the same solution as this needs to catch a possible `mousedown` event before getting to `focusin`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57756490/8285811).

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, the event object itself does not distinguish the means of access. What you *can* do is to bind a `mousedown` listener, which will fire before `focus`, and set some timestamp flag that you compare to some threshold value in your `focus` handler.

Comment: Note that this distinguishes between tab and click, but it will not help you distinguish tab from `.focus()`, but then I don't know if that's somethin you want. If you do want that, perhaps you could implement a global keyup listener for `tab` and compare the proximity between the latest tab and your focus event, but that seems... arduous.

Comment: It does indeed seem arduous. I'm not worried about `.focus()` triggering my event, so everything should work as you originally pointed out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```js
(function() {
  const tabHistory = [];

  window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    const code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    const index = tabHistory.length === 0 ? 1 : tabHistory.length + 1;

    if (code == 9) {
      tabHistory.push({
        element: e.target,
        index
      });

      console.log(index, e.target, tabHistory);
    }
  });
})();
```

I recommend keeping a track of the focused elements, this way you make sure the user will be able to tab as you expected.

[image: Console Screenshot]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this is the better answer, because of the "target" piece, which you can use to match any target in a more generalizable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check focus event on specific input by this code

```
$(window).on('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == '9'){

      getFocused(event);
    }

})
var focused = 0;
function getFocused(e){
var ida =  $(':focus').eq(0).prop('id');
    if(ida=='detect' && focused==0){
        focused = 1;
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/LPGLm/6/)