# Highlight table row only when tabbing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to add highlighting when tabbing to a row in my table.  Issue I'm having is that the `focusin` function encompasses both mouse click events and tab key.  I'd only like this to occur when tabbing.  Still new to jQuery/js.  Suggestions please?

```
$( "tr" ).focusin( 
        function() { $(this).addClass("highlight"); } ).focusout( 
                function() {$(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this works fine in FF, and Chrome....IE  9 is the problem here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect focus initiated by tab key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144611/detect-focus-initiated-by-tab-key)

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  Need it to bubble down to children